# How can I list all customElements defined?

Tags: dom, shadow-dom

In looking at [CustomElementRegistry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry) type I cannot find any method that would allow me to iterate over all customElements defined.

Is there a way to enumerate over existing customElements without knowing their 'names' (as per .define() 'name' parameter)?

Comment: Are you looking to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: It's not possible at that time.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I know of would be to override `customElements.define` and have your function save off the info you want and then return the value from the original call. Then things still work the same, except that you can track everything in your own data.

Comment: Sure but I was rather looking for something that I've missed in spec.